# Apache Ignite Commutations SPI failing in Kubernates

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

We have a Ignite server node running in Kuberets and recently the client nodes have been failing to connect/form a cluster.

Below is the the client error, server error, client config and server config respectively.

I think the issue is that the client tcp discovery spi needs to be the TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder rather than TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.  I assume that the client configuration has changed at that is the source of this error.  Confirmation of this would be appreciated.

Client error:

```
12-May-2022 15:36:00.954 SEVERE [main] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, consistentId=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, fd00:85:4001:5:e042:a2ad:6e48:1bf6%eth0], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /[fd00:85:4001:5:e042:a2ad:6e48:1bf6%eth0]:0], discPort=0, order=2785, intOrder=1394, lastExchangeTime=1652369742483, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=true], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=3, topic=TOPIC_JOB, topicOrd=0, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridJobExecuteRequest [subjId=081969c6-308c-4acb-8947-a25ff46e20cf, sesId=48349e8b081-081969c6-308c-4acb-8947-a25ff46e20cf, jobId=88349e8b081-081969c6-308c-4acb-8947-a25ff46e20cf, startTaskTime=1652369743792, timeout=9223372036854775807, taskName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$ClearTask, userVer=0, taskClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$ClearTask, ldrParticipants=null, cpSpi=null, createTime=1652369743802, clsLdrId=66349e8b081-081969c6-308c-4acb-8947-a25ff46e20cf, depMode=SHARED, dynamicSiblings=false, forceLocDep=true, sesFullSup=false, internal=true, topPred=null, part=-1, topVer=null, execName=null]]]
class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Failed to send message (node left topology): TcpDiscoveryNode [id=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, consistentId=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, fd00:85:4001:5:e042:a2ad:6e48:1bf6%eth0], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /[fd00:85:4001:5:e042:a2ad:6e48:1bf6%eth0]:0], discPort=0, order=2785, intOrder=1394, lastExchangeTime=1652369742483, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=true]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:417)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1264)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:691)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.createCommunicationClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:481)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.reserveClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:240)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1195)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1142)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2101)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2196)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1452)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:665)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:535)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:846)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:509)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:465)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.executeClearTask(GridCacheAdapter.java:1289)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.clear(GridCacheAdapter.java:1235)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.clear(GridCacheAdapter.java:1189)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.clear(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1673)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.clear(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1156)
at com.niksun.services.web.dashboard.cache.IgniteCache.clear(IgniteCache.java:75)
at com.niksun.prime.mgr.LicenseCache.loadLicense(LicenseCache.java:192)
at com.niksun.prime.mgr.LicenseCache.getInstance(LicenseCache.java:90)
at com.niksun.prime.mgr.LicenseCache.getInstance(LicenseCache.java:84)
at com.niksun.services.misc.impl.LicenseServiceImpl.loadProdTable(LicenseServiceImpl.java:445)
at com.niksun.services.misc.impl.LicenseServiceImpl.<init>(LicenseServiceImpl.java:67)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
12-May-2022 15:36:00.958 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], err=null, rebalanced=true, wasRebalanced=true]
12-May-2022 15:36:00.959 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Completed partition exchange [localNode=081969c6-308c-4acb-8947-a25ff46e20cf, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, consistentId=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, fd00:85:4001:5:e042:a2ad:6e48:1bf6%eth0], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /[fd00:85:4001:5:e042:a2ad:6e48:1bf6%eth0]:0], discPort=0, order=2785, intOrder=1394, lastExchangeTime=1652369742483, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=true], rebalanced=true, done=true, newCrdFut=null], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0]]
12-May-2022 15:36:00.959 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Exchange timings [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], stage="Waiting in exchange queue" (0 ms), stage="Exchange parameters initialization" (0 ms), stage="Determine exchange type" (3 ms), stage="Exchange done" (2 ms), stage="Total time" (5 ms)]
12-May-2022 15:36:00.960 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Exchange longest local stages [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0]]
12-May-2022 15:36:00.960 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], crd=false]
12-May-2022 15:36:00.975 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Skipping rebalancing (no affinity changes) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2788, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=54d36d7e-0c96-4e54-9f5e-f6043370b433, client=true]
Spring context in getLicenseService not yet available, creating our own LicenseServiceImpl com.niksun.services.misc.impl.LicenseServiceImpl@4f36fc2d
Spring context for systemManagerService is not yet available; creating our own SystemManagerServiceImpl
```

Server error:

```
[14:57:10,056][SEVERE][sys-stripe-4-#5][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=11df0a62-6f00-47f2-aac8-2c0303d4f793, consistentId=11df0a62-6f00-47f2-aac8-2c0303d4f793, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, fd00:85:4001:5:c945:1c29:291a:1e84%eth0], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /fd00:85:4001:5:c945:1c29:291a:1e84%eth0:0], discPort=0, order=2746, intOrder=1375, lastExchangeTime=1652367331026, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=true], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=4, val=Configuration, hasValBytes=true], val=CacheObjectImpl [val=null, hasValBytes=true], prevVal=null, super=GridDhtAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest [onRes=true, nearNodeId=null, nearFutId=0, flags=near]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Failed to send message (node left topology): TcpDiscoveryNode [id=11df0a62-6f00-47f2-aac8-2c0303d4f793, consistentId=11df0a62-6f00-47f2-aac8-2c0303d4f793, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, fd00:85:4001:5:c945:1c29:291a:1e84%eth0], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /fd00:85:4001:5:c945:1c29:291a:1e84%eth0:0], discPort=0, order=2746, intOrder=1375, lastExchangeTime=1652367331026, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=true]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:417)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1264)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:691)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.createCommunicationClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:481)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.reserveClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:240)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.CommunicationWorker.processDisconnect(CommunicationWorker.java:376)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.CommunicationWorker.body(CommunicationWorker.java:174)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$6.body(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:928)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
```

Client config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
    default-init-method="init">

    <!--  Ignite configurations -->

    <bean id="igniteConfiguration" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="igniteClientInstance" />
        <property name="clientMode" value="true" />
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
        <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="0" />
        <property name="communicationSpi" ref="communicationSpi" />
        <property name="discoverySpi" ref="discoverySpi" />

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <array>
                <ref bean="allSessionsCacheConfiguration" />
            </array>
        </property>

        <property name="clusterStateOnStart" value="ACTIVE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="communicationSpi" class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
        <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="discoverySpi" class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder" ref="ipFinder" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ipFinder" class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder"> 
        <property name="shared" value="false" /> 
        <property name="addresses"> 
            <list> 
                <value>ourSerivce.********:47500</value> 
            </list> 
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <!--  Ignite caches -->

    <bean id="allSessionsCacheConfiguration" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <property name="name" value="ALL_SESSIONS_CACHE" />
        <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Server config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with this
    work for additional information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF
    licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the
    License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
    WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
    License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License. -->

    <!-- Ignite configuration with all defaults and enabled p2p deployment and
    enabled events. --> 
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <!-- Data Source bean to postgress --> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="pgDataSource"> 
            <property name="driverClassName"   value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property> 
            <property name="url"    value="jdbc:postgresql://nkw-mnomni-postgres.24e36999-de38-5220-862b-94de4c280a96:5432/ngen"></property>
            <property name="username" value="*****"></property> 
            <property name="password" value="*****"></property> 
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"> 
            <property name="workDirectory" value="/ignite/work"/>
            <property name="dataStorageConfiguration"> 
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration"> 
                    <property  name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration"> 
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration"> 
                            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="false"/> 
                        </bean> 
                    </property>
                    <property name="walPath" value="/ignite/wal"/> 
                    <property name="walArchivePath" value="/ignite/walarchive"/> 
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="discoverySpi"> 
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi"> 
                    <property  name="ipFinder"> 
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                            <property name="namespace" value="********"/>
                            <property name="serviceName" value="ourSerivce"/> 
                        </bean>
                    </property> 
                </bean> 
            </property> 
        </bean> 
    </beans>
```

Comment: Where are the clients? Are they also inside k8s? It looks like the client found the cluster but was unable to open further connections. This would happen if the clients were on a different network and you were trying to connect using a service (for example).

Comment: @StephenDarlington, there are three clients, all inside k8tes on the same network.

Comment: @StephenDarlington for what its worth they are also in the same name space.

Comment: Is IPv6 routable? Try adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your JVM_OPTS. What are your k8s network policies? Nodes all need to be talk to one another (ports 47500 and 47100 by default).